# DHT22 code problems

Tags: python, dht22

I've been having problems integrating the code used to extract temp/humidity measurements from the DHT22 into a larger python script. The following code works without issue -

```
import Adafruit_DHT as dht
h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)
print h
print t
```

When the above script is run the shell prints the temperature and humidity readings as expected. However, if I try to incorporate line 2 (dht.read_retry) into an if statement or a while loop I either encounter an error or the shell becomes unresponsive. For example, if I run the following script nothing happens:

```
import Adafruit_DHT as dht

var = 1
list1 = []

if var == 1:
    h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)
    list1.append(h)
    list1.append(t)

print list1
```

I would expect the shell to print the list but nothing happens. And in other, more elaborate, scripts I get errors relating to the line containing dht.read_retry.

Does anyone know why this occurs? I have some experience with python but this is my first Raspberry Pi project. Could it be because I'm using the python shell or am I using the Adafruit_DHT module incorrectly? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the eror message?

Comment: I didn't actually get an error when I ran the above code, nothing happened.

Comment: But you menton running more elaborate scripts with an error? Also what happens if you create a .py file with the above code and run that?

Comment: Ah right, I'm away for a few days so can't get to my Pi. The error involved 'module', it wasn't 'module not found' but something to do with reading dht.read_retry. Sorry, I can't be more specific. I just don't get why you can extract the temp/humidity values in the first script but not in a loop.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong because I'm not a python guru, but it looks like the read loop will loop forever because val is always 1. Therefore you won't get to the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, those humidity sensors cannot be queried too often. From the top of my ahead, and from the datasheets, both the DHT11 and DHT22 cannot see queries less than 1-2 seconds apart. If you do not respect that interval, they wont answer.

Comment: I was running the loop every 10 seconds so I don't think it was that.

Answer (score 0):

First I enabled the SPI, I2C and 1-wire on raspberry py using

> sudo raspi-config

command and selecting ***Interfacing Options***.

Then enabled the resistor using the following two commands.

> sudo pigpiod
>
> pigs pud 4 u

Now it's working as I expected.